# Getting data from XML node in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am retrieving an XML data from url and I want to extract data from the particular nodes.

Here is my XML Data

```
<person>
  <first-name>ABC</first-name>
  <last-name>XYZ</last-name>
</person>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child->first-name . "<br>";
  }
```

PHP returns this error:

```
Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'
```

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Also please see the [Basic Usage of SimpleXML, especially *Example #3 Getting <line>* in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you cannot use `-` in the variable name. From what I can gather though, you are simply trying to print out the tag name and value. If so, you're probably after this:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo "{$child->getName()}: $child <br />";
}
```

Comment: Yes Ofcourse. I am trying to print the tag value. It did worked. 
Thank you

Comment: @juco: Please just comment and link to the existing answer with these common questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
<person>
  <firstname>ABC</firstname>
  <lastname>XYZ</lastname>
</person>
```

and then :

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child->firstname . "<br>";
  }
```

Does it works ?

Edit : you won't have any datas in `$xml->children()` cause you don't have any. Try to do something like this :

```
<person>
  <firstname>ABC</firstname>
  <lastname>XYZ</lastname>
  <other>
    <first>111</first>
    <second>222</second>
  </other>
</person>

<?php 
$content = file_get_contents("test.xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{   
    echo $child->getName() . ": " .$child->first . "<br>";
}

 ?>
```

this will echo this :

```
firstname: 
lastname: 
other: 111
```

I you want to have the first node, you can simply do :

```
echo $xml->firstname
```

Comment: No. It doesnot. The $child->getName returns the node name only. But $child->firstname Or $child->first-name doesnot return the node's data

Answer (score 0):

The `'-'` isn't allowed in a variable name. `$child->first-name` is interpreted as `$child->first minus name`. You should find another way to get the content.